# Reverse search ini section

Tags: bash, shell, ini

Assume this .ini file.

```ini
[section_x]
my_value=abc
another_value=def

[section_2]
my_value=stv
another_value=xyz

[this_one]
my_value=something
another_value=sure
```

Assume the system has the value `something` loaded in it's environment variable.
Using bash, how can I search the .ini file to match the value, and then load that section, in this case `this_one`? Based on the section, it then loads `another_value`.

In this case, the outcome would be `sure`.

Another example for clarity: if the system had `stv` loaded in it's env, the outcome is `xyz`.

Comment: Do you mean, you have an environment variable `$variable` with the value `something` (`variable=something`)?

Comment: Yes, environment variable. You can assume your own variable name. Important in the value of it, in this case indeed `something`.

Comment: What is the desired outcom, if `something` occurs in more than one section?

Comment: What is the meaning of _load that section_  in the context of bash?

Comment: The values for `Something` is unique in this case, so no need for multiple occurunces.

Comment: `LOOKED_UP=$(grep -A1 'something' this.ini | tail -1 | cut -d '=' -f 2)`

Answer (score 0):

As long as `$variable` doesn't contain anything special, you can use awk in "paragraph mode":

```
$ awk -v RS= "/my_value=$variable/" file | grep -Po '(?<=another_value=).*'
sure
```

Alternatively, in case `grep` doesn't support `-P` or negative lookbehinds:

```
$ awk -v RS= "/my_value=$variable/" file | sed '/another_value/!d;s/.*=//'
sure
```

Comment: I don't know why, but my terminal returns nothing when using this code.

Comment: @KevinC `variable=something` together with one of the commands do work here (second gives `sure`).

Comment: @KevinC I tried on 3 systems, all work fine. It's possible that your `grep` doesn't support `-P`. In that case try e.g. `sed '/another_value/!d;s/.*=//'`.

Comment: The awk doesn’t return anything :o

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```bash
$ v="something"
$ awk -F= -v value="$v" '$1 ~ "my_value" && $2 ~ value {getline; print $2}' file
sure
```

Comment: Gives me: def
xyz
true

Comment: @KevinC What version of awk are you using?

Comment: I have a mac, my test vm is centos 8, and my testing environment is most likely an alpine docker image. On my test vm, it is 4.2.1.

Comment: @KevinC I just tested in a `python:3.12-rc-alpine` container and it works fine there

Comment: This works only if the second line (`another_value`) follows the identifying line (`my_value`). "Based on the section, it then loads another_value" sounds like this guarantee can't be made.

Comment: @steffen yes indeed, that is the assumption given OPs file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `another_value` line does not appear *before* the `my_value`
line, how about a `sed` solution:

```
export variable="something"
sed -n "/my_value=$variable/,/^$/p" file | sed "/another_value/!d;s/.*=//"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` one-liner that finds `"something"` and then returns the next value for `another_value` can be:

```bash
awk -F= -v ev="something" 'av && $1=="another_value" {print $2; exit} $2==ev {av=1}' file
```

Where `av` is just a flag variable for `another_value` which is set nonzero when the entry with `something` as its value is reached leading to the next `another_value` to be captured and output.

The benefit here is you have a single call to `awk` instead of calls to multiple utilities.

**Example Use/Output**

With your example input in `dat/some.ini`, you would have:

```
$ awk -F= -v ev="something" 'av && $1=="another_value" {print $2; exit} $2==ev {av=1}' dat/some.ini
sure
```

Or if you wanted to find any of the other values, just change what you provide as the variable `ev`, e.g.

```
awk -F= -v ev="abc" 'av && $1=="another_value" {print $2; exit} $2==ev {av=1}' dat/some.ini
def
```

and

```
$ awk -F= -v ev="stv" 'av && $1=="another_value" {print $2; exit} $2==ev {av=1}' dat/some.ini
xyz
```